# Cant Overflow The Buffer For Shell Coding

Tags: c++, c, shellcode

I have this shell code which is suppose to open a MessageBox. It works when testing it with https://github.com/NytroRST/ShellcodeCompiler, however when I create a new console application using c and try to compile this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned char rc[] = "\x31\xC3\x89\x64\xE2\x80\xB9\x41\x30\xE2\x80\xB9\x40\x0C\xE2\x80\xB9\x70\x14\xC2\xAD\xE2\x80\x93\xC2\xAD\xE2\x80\xB9\x58\x10\xE2\x80\xB9\x53\x3C\x01\xC3\x9A\xE2\x80\xB9\x52\x78\x01\xC3\x9A\xE2\x80\xB9\x72\x20\x01\xC3\x9E\x31\xC3\x89\x41\xC2\xAD\x01\xC3\x98\xC2\x81\x38\x47\x65\x74\x50\x75\xC3\xB4\xC2\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6F\x63\x41\x75\xC3\xAB\xC2\x81\x78\x08\x64\x64\x72\x65\x75\xC3\xA2\xE2\x80\xB9\x72\x24\x01\xC3\x9E\x66\xE2\x80\xB9\x0C\x4E\x49\xE2\x80\xB9\x72\x1C\x01\xC3\x9E\xE2\x80\xB9\x14\xC5\xBD\x01\xC3\x9A\x31\xC3\x89\x53\x52\x51\x68\x61\x72\x79\x41\x68\x4C\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4C\x6F\x61\x64\x54\x53\xC3\xBF\xC3\x92\x92\xC3\x84\x0C\x59\x50\x31\xC3\x80\x66\xC2\xB8\x6C\x6C\x50\x68\x33\x32\x2E\x64\x68\x75\x73\x65\x72\x54\xC3\xBF\x54\x24\x10\xC6\x92\xC3\x84\x0C\x50\x31\xC3\x80\xC2\xB8\x6F\x78\x41\x23\x50\xC6\x92\x6C\x24\x03\x23\x68\x61\x67\x65\x42\x68\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x54\xC3\xBF\x74\x24\x10\xC3\xBF\x54\x24\x1C\xC6\x92\xC3\x84\x0C\x50\x31\xC3\x80\xC2\xB8\x65\x73\x73\x23\x50\xC6\x92\x6C\x24\x03\x23\x68\x50\x72\x6F\x63\x68\x45\x78\x69\x74\x54\xC3\xBF\x74\x24\x20\xC3\xBF\x54\x24\x20\xC6\x92\xC3\x84\x0C\x50\x31\xC3\x80\xC2\xB8\x59\x6F\x75\x23\x50\xC6\x92\x6C\x24\x03\x23\x68\x41\x72\x65\x20\x68\x48\x6F\x77\x20\x68\x48\x65\x79\x20\x54\x31\xC3\x80\x50\x68\x54\x65\x73\x74\x54\x31\xC3\x80\x50\xC3\xBF\x74\x24\x04\xC3\xBF\x74\x24\x14\x31\xC3\x80\x50\xC3\xBF\x54\x24\x34\x92\xC3\x84\x20\x31\xC3\x80\x50\xC3\xBF\x54\x24\x04\x6e";

int main() {
    (*(void(*)()) rc)();
}
```

It always throws an Access Violation Exception after running it, I can get rid of this exception if I change the memory protections at the location of the shell codes injection. But yet it still does not display the MessageBox. I am certain the shell code works because the link above has a program that tests the shellcode and it works flawlessly. Only difference between their exploitation approach is that they are using c++ to do it and im using c.

Comment: You need to change the memory page permissions and check if the shell code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VirtualProtect`,

```cpp
DWORD oldProt = 0;
VirtualProtect(rc, sizeof(rc), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProt);
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this as changing virtual protection doesn't only change the size you need, it will change the entire page protection. Also, for some reason, I did this in the past and it crashed in x86_64 but not x86.

Comment: @thedemons this worked for me, the memory address for the buffer was always read only. To be fair I should've called `VirtualQuery()` and removed `rc` as the size. Ex `VirtualProtect(rc, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProt)`

Comment: This code has undefined behavior in x64. Why is it marked as accepted?

Comment: @JohnySiuu Just because it works doesn't mean you should do it. *the memory address for the buffer was always read only* No, it isn't, because it wasn't declared as `const`.

Comment: @tokputi the shell code only works for x86

Comment: @thedemons doesnt need to be declared as `const`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to call the address of `rc`, which its [Memory Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) is `PAGE_READWRITE`, hence the access violation error.

You will have to allocate a buffer and set the protection to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` in order for it to work.

Helper function:

```cpp
void* AllocFunction(const void* rawData, const size_t size)
{
    void* pFunction = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (pFunction == nullptr) throw;

    memcpy(pFunction, rawData, size);

    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(pFunction, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &dwOldProtect)) throw;

    return pFunction;
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
void (*lpFunction)() = nullptr;
*(void**)&lpFunction = AllocFunction(rc, sizeof(rc));

lpFunction();
```